# Deno Unstable Flag

Tags: typescript, puppeteer, deno, deno-puppeteer

I read though puppeteer documentation and ran every require command but when I run the sample code even with the `--unstable` flag . Deno seem to throw the same error as shown below

```sh
$ deno run --unstable --allow-all  scrap.ts 
Check file:///Users/kudiadmin/Desktop/personal/deno-paystack/scrap.ts
error: TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utime' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
    await Deno.utime(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
               ~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.93.0/fs/copy.ts:96:16

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utimeSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utimeSync' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
    Deno.utimeSync(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
         ~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.93.0/fs/copy.ts:111:10

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utime' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
    await Deno.utime(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
               ~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.93.0/fs/copy.ts:135:16

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utimeSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utimeSync' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
    Deno.utimeSync(dest, statInfo.atime, statInfo.mtime);
         ~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.93.0/fs/copy.ts:160:10

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utime' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utime' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
    await Deno.utime(dest, srcStatInfo.atime, srcStatInfo.mtime);
               ~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.93.0/fs/copy.ts:183:16

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'utimeSync' does not exist on type 'typeof Deno'. 'Deno.utimeSync' is an unstable API. Did you forget to run with the '--unstable' flag?
    Deno.utimeSync(dest, srcStatInfo.atime, srcStatInfo.mtime);
         ~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.93.0/fs/copy.ts:214:10

Found 6 errors.
```

here is the code:

```
import puppeteer from "https://deno.land/x/puppeteer@9.0.2/mod.ts";

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://example.com");
await page.screenshot({ path: "example.png" });

await browser.close();
```

deno specification are :

```sh
$ deno --version
deno 1.20.5 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 10.0.139.6
typescript 4.6.2
```

Comment: my output for `deno --version` is identical to yours but I only see the errors you are seeing if I don't specify `--unstable` 

Comment: I find it unlikely any of these will help but because this _might_ be an issue specific to your environment at the moment you might try the following: delete Deno caches, uninstall Deno, reboot OS, reinstall Deno

Comment: Not necessarily related to your issue: you appear to be using a version of the `std` library which is not guaranteed to be compatible with the version of Deno that you are using. See the [notes in the manual about versioning](https://deno.land/manual@v1.20.5/standard_library#versioning-and-stability). Also, here's [a link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/dotland/main/versions.json) to the file where a mapping of version compat is maintained ([permalink](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/dotland/d633a47c74b8b6543d9061386793a55988e43bad/versions.json) to latest revision).

Comment: The [troubleshooting](https://deno.land/manual@v1.20.5/standard_library#troubleshooting) section addresses your case directly.